# ¿Cómo comparo filas usando bucles for?

Tags: r, condiciones, bucles

Tengo un dataframe tal que

```
id = c(ES150010005163, ES150010005163, ES150010005163, ES150010005163, ES150010005167)
días = c(1820, 1820, 1820, 1820, 2223)
año = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2008)
producción = c(129, 156, 157, 172, 186)
cría = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
tiempo_cambio = c(405, 730, 1093, 1460, 727)

datos <- as.data.frame ( id, días, año, producción, cría, tiempo_cambio)

datos

id              días  año    producción cría  tiempo_cambio
ES150010005163  1820  2007   129          1    405
ES150010005163  1820  2008   156          1    730
ES150010005163  1820  2009   157          2    1093
ES150010005163  1820  2010   172          1    1460
ES150010005167  2223  2008   186          1    727
```

y he definido una matriz con las dimensiones correspondientes

```
mimatriz<-matrix(NA, ncol = (ncol(datos)-1 + (ncambios - 1))*9, nrow = nrow(ov))
```

Debo hacer un bucle que:

1- Compare si el elemento 1 de la columna 1 es igual al elemento 2 de la columna 1.

Lo he intentado haciendo

```
for (i in 1:nrow(datos)){      
  if(datos[i, 1] == datos[i + 1, 1]){
    print(paste("Ok"))
  }
}
```

La salida es:

```
[1] "Ok"
[1] "Ok"
[1] "Ok"
```

Pero me muestra error

> Error in if (datos[i, 1] == datos[i + 1, 1]) { :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

Qué puede estar pasando?

2- Luego, si la condición se cumple, quiero que

```
2.1 Escriba los elementos de la columna 1 y 5, fila 1, en la fila 1 de "mimatrix", columns 1 y 5.
2.2 Escriba en la columna 6 de "mimatrix", el valor de la fila 2 de la columna 6 
2.3 Escriba en la columna 7 de "mimatrix", el valor de la fila 2 de la columna 3
```

Cómo debo indicar esto dentro del bucle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás iterando por todas las filas de `datos` pero al mismo tiempo comparas los elementos de la fila actual con el de la fila siguiente, ¿Que ocurre entonces cuando llegas al último elemento (fila 5)? en ese momento vas comparar un dato contra otro dato inexistente:

```
i <- 5
datos[i + 1, 1]
[1] NA
```

Y ahí tienes la explicación del error, cualquier comparación con un valor `NA` será `NA`, en cuyo caso falla el `if()` por que esta esperando una valor `TRUE` o  `FALSE`.

La solución dependerá de la definición que te hayan dado en este ejercicio para tratar el último elemento. Lo habitual en estos casos es iterar desde el el primer elemento hasta el ante último:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(datos)-1)){      
  if(datos[i, 1] == datos[i + 1, 1]){
    print(paste("Ok"))
  }
}
```